# Obtaining tight edges from a graph to find an MST

Tags: graph-theory, linear-programming, duality-theorems

As far as I understand, to obtain an optimal solution of the Dual of the MST, meaning:

\begin{align}
~\max &~ z (|V|-1) + \sum_{S  \subseteq V : |S| \neq \emptyset} (|S|-1) y_{s} \\
\label{DMST2}
s.t. &~ z + \sum_{S: (i,j) \in E(S)}^{} y_{s} \leq w_{ij} &  \forall (i,j) \in E \\
\label{DMST3}
&~y_{s} \leq 0 & \forall S  \subseteq V : |S| \neq \emptyset 
\end{align}

we have to start with the trivial partition and add tight edges to it, one by  one.

What I don't undestand is how we obtain those tight edges. Suppose we have the $K_5$ with the edgweights being the sum of the corresponding vertices (vertices being $1,2,3,4,5$). How can I see that $(1,2)$ is a tight edge?